# SonarQube limit heap size for execution

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarqube-web

I am using sonarqube locally and I want to limit heap size (Memory size) which used by sonar while execution. Can say I want to allow max size 512mb. So what can I do for this? Even wanted to know that is there any to execute sonarqube analyzing faster?

Thank you!

Comment: SonarQube makes intensive use of your hard drive. Be aware that part of the analysis is done on the build agent. The heaps size can be changed in the SonarQube config files. However, the default setting should be enough in almost all cases.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I have ec2 server and when I scan multiple projects at a time server gets stopped as sonar scanner is taking too much memory to scan the project. So do you have any idea what should be the minimum requirement of the hard disk as well read/write operation of the ec2 server to run large size of projects or multiple projects at a time?